# Installing tensorflow 2.0 in anaconda on computer with no Internet

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I work in an organization where there is no internet in our workstations.I wanted to install Tensorflow 2.0.
I have already installed anaconda 4.4 (which has python 3.6) on my PC.
Since there is no internet I installed tensorflow 1.2.0 with immense difficulty as it was dependent on many other libraries. Finally, someone who had done this earlier told me that I need to install the following prerequisites below before installing Tensorflor 1.2.0

1. protobuf-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
2. webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
3. html5lib-0.9999999
4. backports.weakref-1.0rc1-py3-none-any.whl
5. Markdown-2.2.0
6. bleach-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
7. After all the pre-requsites (till no 6 above) were installed I installed tensorflow-1.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl through pip.

But after that installing Keras became the next issue as it was again dependent on a number of other libraries.
I came to know that Tensorflow 2.0 has Keras bundled with it and so I plan to install the same. Even to use new features I intend to install Tensorflow 2.0 but I need to know in advance which all prerequisite libraries(similar to the list above) are required so that I can download them all at once from internet and then copy the same to my workstation.
I am even open to installing  a higher version of Tensorflow (*That can work with anaconda 4.4 / python 3.6*) provided the number of prerequisite dependencies is less(so that i dont have to bear the pain and keep hopping between internet PC and my offline workstation) or is bundled together.
Additional Info -  My official PC is having Windows 10 OS. *I am relatively new to python.*

Comment: I haven't used this myself, but have you considered creating a conda environment with Tensorflow, Keras etc on an internet-connected PC, then using "conda-pack" to transfer it to your airgapped machine? https://github.com/conda/conda-pack

Comment: Unfortunately the internet PC is a  linux thin client and work PC is  Windows 10 . All I can do is download something and copy to my work PC. Cannot even install something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an environment on windows that contains linux packages, then package it with `conda pack` and ship it to your airgapped machine. I havn't tested this approach, since I don't have a dual boot at the moment:

```
conda create linux_env
conda activate linux_env 
conda config --env --set subdir linux-64
conda install -c tensorflow==2.0
conda deactivate
conda install conda-pack
conda pack -n linux_env
```